# Drop a pandas DataFrame row that comes after a row that contains a particular value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

I am trying to drop all rows that come after a row which has `yes` inside the `'Ammend'` column

df:

```
  Ammend
 0  no
 1  yes
 2  no
 3  no
 4  yes
 5  no
```

Required output df:

```
  Ammend
 0  no
 1  yes
 3  no
 4  yes
```

Look at the following code:

```
df = df.drop(df[df['Amended' == 'yes']], inplace=True)
```

Returns a `KeyError: False` error message

I have tried many different variations of this using different methods like `.index.tolist()` and `.loc`
but I can't seem to figure it out anyway.

I have also tried truncate:

```
filings_df.truncate(after=filings_df.loc[filings_df['Filings'] == '10-K/A'].index[0], before = filings_df.loc[filings_df['Filings'] == '10-K/A'].index[1])
```

This returns:

> IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Comment: A silly question. Do you have two/more yes together in your `dataframe`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(525)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Other': np.random.rand(10), 'Ammend': np.random.choice(['yes', 'no'], 10)})
df
```

```
      Other Ammend
0  0.750282     no
1  0.379455     no
2  0.766467    yes
3  0.351025     no
4  0.965993     no
5  0.709159     no
6  0.838831    yes
7  0.218321     no
8  0.573360    yes
9  0.738974     no
```

Output:

```
df.drop(index=df[df['Ammend'].shift() == 'yes'].index)

      Other Ammend
0  0.750282     no
1  0.379455     no
2  0.766467    yes
4  0.965993     no
5  0.709159     no
6  0.838831    yes
8  0.573360    yes
```

Comment: For your generated data frame there would only be 3 rows dropped. Corresponding to the three "yes".

Comment: only rows 3, 7 and 9

Comment: Hey, I just realized my desired output df was wrong. I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `pandas.Series.ne` with `shift` trick:

```
s = df["Ammend"]
new_df = df[~s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum().duplicated(keep="first")]
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
  Ammend
0     no
1    yes
2     no
4    yes
5     no
```